# I can't store data into MongoDB(Atlas) on Postman (Node.js with express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

It’s my first post.

I’m trying to post a data which is object includes “title”,”body”,”snippet” into backend which I use Mongo DB Atlas.

However when I test it on postman, I can’t store those data into a schema which is prepared in model.

The error message:

```
 “   title: MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Path `title` is required.
        at new ValidatorError ”
```

Others(body,snippet) are also null.

app.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      cors = require('cors'),
      app = express(),
      blogRoutes = require('./routes/blogRoute');

// connect to mongoDB
const dbURI = '';
mongoose.connect(dbURI,{ useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true } )
.then(result => {
    // Listen for requests
    app.listen(3000);
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));

// Middleware & static files
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// cors
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }))

//Blog Router
app.use('/blogs/api',blogRoutes);

//404
app.use((req,res) => {
    res.render('404',{ title:'Not Found' });
})
```

Model file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    snippet:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    body:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
}, { timestamps:true })

// create model
const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog',blogSchema);

module.exports = Blog;
```

Controller(store):

```
// Store
const blog_create_post = async (req,res) => {
    const {title,snippet,body} = req.body;
    try {
        const blog = await Blog.create({ title,snippet,body });
        res.status(201).json(blog);
        console.log(blog);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400);
    }
}
```

router:
// Store

```
router.post('/',blogController.blog_create_post)
```

Even though GET works fine, I’m stuck in this error for a long time on POST method…

I would appreciate if you suggest something.

Comment: Hide your password in mongodbconnection url

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong in sending data through postman, try to add console.log(req.body) and see whether it contains all the field or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mongoose schema, you have mentioned required for the title as below and while creating a new document mostly it is empty hence the error title: MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Path `title` is required.
at new ValidatorError

```
title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
```

Also, your Controller is catering title properly.

It can be the way you are sending data from the postman if you are sending raw and JSON then add below middleware comment

```
app.use(express.json());
```